# is "at your disposal" correct? why - why not?

Tags: british-english

My mother tongue isn't English, and recently I came across this expression:

> You have a collection of smileys at your disposal.

For me, the word **disposal** means "discarding some waste, throwing something away, getting rid of something".

I have been searching the web, and I found a Collins Dictionairy's (online, british version) description:

> Disposal (noun) - the power or opportunity to make use of someone or something (esp in the phrase at one's disposal)

That matches the use I have mention before, but for me, it still sounds wrong.

Is the expression "having something at your disposal" correct?

Comment: Similar question at [English.Stackexchange](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21394/what-are-the-implications-of-at-my-disposal)

Comment: Why? Because it's a phrase.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> it still sounds wrong

It sounds perfectly normal to me and it's used reasonably commonly.

> As a programmer, I have a number of useful tools **at my disposal** including a powerful IDE and a well documented API.

Comment: Thank you. It is the first time I came across and it sounded kind of weird to me.

Comment: You're welcome, but no need to say thanks on Stack Exchange. You should just accept (click the little green tick) and optionally upvote if you found an answer helpful.

Comment: Completely normal to me as well (a Brit).  Many words in English can mean different things depending on context.

Comment: @Arcsn it is not advisable to accept an answer so soon. Please read [this](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) help section.

Comment: @Usernew, I accept answers as soon as `receive an answer that answers [my] question well`

Comment: @JamesWebster Others should be given a chance to present their answers. Answers with more in-depth explanation so that the asker will have a better understanding of it. Details like why "having something at your disposal" is correct, and what it means and so on.

Comment: @JamesWebster The question is "is 'at your disposal' correct? why - why not?" If you want to say something like "it sounds fine to me" or some minor detail, then say it via comment. :)